# Join of tables returning incorrect results

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

There are 4 sql tables:

```
Listings(Amount, GroupKey, Key, MemberKey),
Loans(Amount, GroupKey, Key, ListingKey),
Members(City, GroupKey, Key)
Groups(GroupRank, Key, MemberKey)
```

Now, if one wants to find out the loans which are also listings and find the members city and GroupRank for the members in the loan table. Here, the group table contains information about grous of which members are a part of.
 and also perform a select operation as given below:

```
select Listings.Amount, Members.City, Groups.GroupRank
from listings, loans, members, groups
where Listings.Key=Loans.ListingKey and
    Members.Key=Listings.MemberKey and
    Listings.GroupKey=Groups.Key
```

The above join is giving an incorrect result, please point out where I am going wrong.
Also I am new to SQL so please excuse the novice question.

Comment: In what way is the original query giving an incorrect result? Can you clarify your question? It isn't clear what you are trying to acieve.

Comment: @MarkBannister Thanks for improving the question. I have made edits to the question, hope that it becomes clear now

Comment: I think what people mean when saying to clarify the question is, what does the above `SELECT` return and what do you expect it to return? Also what DBMS are you targeting? You can't just select all the available DBMS types.

Comment: Do all the tables need GroupKey? What does it mean if a loan has one GroupKey and the corresponding listing has another GroupKey?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: The rows from listing themselves get added to the loan table. Therefore if a loan has a GroupKey the corresponding listing also has the same group key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: The following is just a guess what your problem is. Like others said, clearify your question.

You want to `JOIN`
( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/join.html )
those tables. What you write is just another form of a join, meaning it has the same effect. But you "joined" a bit too much. To make things clearer a syntax has been invented to make things clearer and avoid such mistakes. Read more about it in the link given above.

What you want to achieve can be done like this:

```
SELECT
Listings.Amount, Members.City, Groups.GroupRank
FROM
Listings
INNER JOIN Groups ON Listings.GroupKey=Groups.Key
INNER JOIN Members ON Members.Key=Listings.MemberKey
```

You don't do a SELECT on the Loans table, you don't need it in this query.

This is the INNER JOIN which will give you a result where every row in table A has an according entry in table B. When this is not the case, you have to use the LEFT or RIGHT JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is related to the join type (INNER). Try LEFT JOIN for example but Mark has right: you should clearify your question.

Comment: I myself have just this much information about the question. Sorry for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would firstly change your query to use the more modern join syntax, which allows *outer* joins. Tr this:

```
select Listings.Amount, Members.City, Groups.GroupRank
from listings
left join loans on Listings.Key=Loans.ListingKey
left join members on Members.Key=Listings.MemberKey
left join groups on Listings.GroupKey=Groups.Key 
    and/or Loans.GroupKey=Groups.Key
    and/or Members.Key=Groups.MemberKey
```

You may need to play with the criteria on the last join (maybe they should be "or" not "and" etc).